# Pointers and dereferenced pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have this declaration in the header file

```
private:
MyIntegerClass *myArr;
MyIntegerClass myIntegerClass;
MyIntegerClass *ptr_myIntegerClass = &myIntegerClass;
```

MyIntegerClass is a class that have one data memeber that holds an integer. It has two member-functions - an accessor and a mutator.

And this is the cpp-file of the Array-class - the class that allocates memory for the array, and fills the array with values and lastly prints the array

```
Array::Array() {

    myArr = new MyIntegerClass[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           ptr_myIntegerClass->setNumber(i);
           myArr[i] = *ptr_myIntegerClass;
    }
}

Array::~Array() { }

void Array::printArray() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << myArr[i].getNumber() << endl;
}
```

I am new to C++ and I have thorough certain knowledge of C and through trial and error made this program that compiles and print these values without errors. But there's a couple things I do not understand:

- Both myArr and ptr_myIntegerClass are pointers. But how could the following be correct:

  ```
    myArr[i] = *ptr_myIntegerClass;
  ```

For what I know - to put an `*` ahead of an pointer means that you dereference the pointer?
right? So how could `myArr` that is a pointer store this dereferenced value? 
Or am I wrong about that `myArr` is a pointer? But why is it declared with a `*` in the header file?

Comment: Why are you using `namespace std`?

Comment: @jeffrey - Eclipse autogenerate this

Comment: I seriously doubt that.

Comment: So who did this if I did not? a ghost?

Comment: Yes. A ghost could explain it. But remove it, for God's sake.

Comment: @Jefffrey - others have also said that Eclipse does this.

Comment: @hetepeperfan - maybe I should. Eclipse may be better for java and android. Any suggestions? visualstudio?

Comment: Some time, please note that 'integer' has only one 'r' in it. And don't try to add to `namespace std`; you don't have permission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The asterisk and the square brackets both decrease the level of dereference. In fact, `myArr[i]` is equivalent to `*(myArr+i)`, and `*ptr_myIntergerClass` is equivalent to `ptr_myIntergerClass[0]`. Therefore, your assignment is equivalent to either

```
*(myArr+i) = *ptr_myIntergerClass;
```

or

```
myArr[i] = ptr_myIntergerClass[0];
```

which are both valid, because both their sides have the same type (i.e. `MyIntergerClass`) and the left side is assignable (i.e. an [lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3601602/335858)).